# Reading a value that is passed in a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stream

I'm reading a file in c++ and I separate value's by space and enter like this

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I'm checking the second part and if it is a 6 I want to `cout` the whole line.

```
5 6
```

code sample:

```
ifstream f;
f.open("sample.txt");
f>>check;
if(check==6){
    cout << check;
}
```

How can I print **the whole line** without storing it? To be clear I just want to print the current value and the last one.

Comment: of course if I'm asking I have searched

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to compare the data, and then do something depending on the result of the comparison, you can *not* avoid storing them somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the whole line, you'll have to store it:

```
struct Record
{
  int first;
  int second;
  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.first;
  input >> r.second;
};

//...
Record r;
while (f >> r)
{
  if (r.second == 6)
  {
    std::cout << r.first << " " << r.second << "\n";
  }
}
```

In the above code, I've *modeled* the input row using a `struct`.  Two values are read and stored.  When the second value is a 6, the first and second values are output.

You don't need a `struct`, but you can use two variables:

```
int first;
int second;
while (f >> first >> second)
{
  if (second == 6)
  {
    std::cout << first << " " << second << "\n";
  }
}
```